# Display Json file inside an html file

Tags: json

I am very new to Json but im trying to display a json file inside an html body.

my json file looks something like this

```
{ items: [
    {
        "thumb":"http://link/link.jpg",
        "title":"title of the link",
                  "link":"http://link.html",
        "popup":"false"
    },
    {
        "thumb":"http://link/link2.jpg",
        "title":"title of the link2",
                  "link":"http://link2.html",
        "popup":"false"
    },
    {
        "thumb":"http://link/link3.jpg",
        "title":"title of the link3",
                  "link":"http://link3.html",
        "popup":"false"
    }
]}
```

and i want have this to be displayed inside my html body document...any suggestions?ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want that exact text to be in your document, or do you want to have that decoded?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question literally:

```
<iframe width="800" height="400" src="your-file.json"></iframe>
```

I'm not sure you *really* want that, though.

- Does the JSON really exist in a file, or are you returning it as an HTTP response?
- Are you really just using plain HTML, or is a server or client-side scripting language playing a role?
- Do you want that plain text in your document, or are you looking to use the data in some way?

Comment: Thanks Bobby!!!, Yes the Json file really exisit in same dir as my html file and its a plain html except i have <img id="navLeft" src="link/navleft.jpg" style="display:none;" onClick="scrollDivLeft()"/> to have it scroll left and right. I dont know if this help. But what should happen is i will have a frame inside my html file that will parse the json file and display a slide show of links and thump size images to scroll left and right :)